# showing in popup window method implementation in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using **Intellij 2016.1** and I was wondering if there's a shortcut to see the method body in a popup window , instead of **jumping** to source code like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> does .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The feature is called **Quick Definition Lookup** (*Main menu* > *View* > *Tool Windows* in the keymap settings). The default combination is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for Mac).

[image: Preferences -> Keymap window]

It appears like

[image: Preview of the popup]

Any editing actions in the popup window lead to jumping into the file where the code is defined.

Comment: for me its just jumping to the source file ... u see it in a **popup window** ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. CMD + Y for me, on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge,

Why would you just want to see the code in a popup? The signature yes, if you hover over the method it will show you the parameter types but if you are looking at body code then Ctrl-Click to jump to the code. Then you can CTRL-ALT Left Arrow to return to the original location

Comment: because i just want a quick reminder of several methods and to go over couple of them fast, with ctrl+click method I need to do a lot of jumping back and forth which isnt ideal at all ...

Comment: You can Ctrl Click then if you do Ctrl Alt Left Arrow you jump back

Answer (score 0):

Try use `option`+`space` (on Mac) on expression to watch implementation in the small window